# Windows Server 2016, How to avoid automatic reboot after updates?

Tags: windows-update, windows-server-2016

I used SCONFIG to change automatic updates to 'Download Only' but I was told it doesn't prevent reboots outside active hours, is that correct?

If so, Do I have to disable the 'reboot' task in Task Scheduler to avoid reboots?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The default in Windows Server 2016 is 'Download Only', which you note you have also verified using `sconfig`.

This setting does not apply updates at all on its own - so no reboots will occur. By default, the server will only reboot if the 'Automatic' setting is selected.The maintenance window only applies to updates applied using the 'Automatic' setting.

**Source**: [Technet](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mu/2016/10/25/__trashed/)

Additionally, you can configure more granular Windows Updates settings using Group Policy, under `Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Updates`.

If applicable to your environment, I would recommend familiarising yourself with the available policies under that heading - in particular the `Configure Automatic Updates` policy, which has granular settings including specifying the automatic maintenance window for automatic updates if selected.